# jquery.ui.dialog open only once

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a  section that i'm trying to load another page into then open as dialog modal.
It works the first time i trigger even to load the page and open as modal but on further try it only load the page in the div "without showing the page itself".

I used the following code.

```
$("#dialogDisplayECC").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 1090,
    modal: true,
    close: function () {
        $("#dialogDisplayECC").dialog("close");
    }
});


function showEccInDialog(pId, pCar, pkmStart, pkmEnd) {
    url = "detail.do?mi=main" + "&pId=" + pId + "&pCar=" + pCar + "&pStart=" + pkmStart + "&pEnd=" + pkmEnd;
    $("#dialogDisplayECC").load(url);
    $("#dialogDisplayECC").dialog("open");

} 

<div id="dialogDisplayECC" style='overflow: auto;'></div>
```

The function showEccInDialog is triggered by a onclick on a div else where.
and it does sends the right parameters to the showEccInDialog because it works the first time.

Thanks for your help

Yan

Comment: could you provide a jfiddle so I can try to solve your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q2645/2/

not sure why it says showEccInDialog  is undefined as on my local machine i dont get such error. i also change the load(url) to load("www.google.com") because the url wouldnt make sense on jfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the scope of your function, it isn't loaded in the context for the onclick call. You could define your function inside your  to make it global but since you are using jquery this solution is better, set it using on document ready and now you got a global function to be called from onclick

http://jsfiddle.net/q2645/3/

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
        var dialogDisplayECC= $( "#dialogDisplayECC" ).dialog( {
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 1090,
            modal: true,
            close: function() {
                $( "#dialogDisplayECC" ).dialog("close");
        }});

        showEccInDialog = function( pId, pCar, pkmStart, pkmEnd ) {
           url =  "detail.do?mi=main" +"&pId=" + pId + "&pCar=" +pCar + "&pStart=" + pkmStart + "&pEnd=" +pkmEnd;
           $( "#dialogDisplayECC" ).load(url);
           dialogDisplayECC.dialog("open");

        }
});
```

Comment: Aboca, thanks for your help it seems that "along with using an old version of jquery.ui" were the problem. It now works flawlesly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dialogDisplayECC= $( "#dialogDisplayECC" ).dialog( {
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 1090,
    modal: true,
    close: function() {
        $( "#dialogDisplayECC" ).dialog("close");
    }

function showEccInDialog( pId, pCar, pkmStart, pkmEnd ) {
   url =  "detail.do?mi=main" +"&pId=" + pId + "&pCar=" +pCar + "&pStart=" + pkmStart + "&pEnd=" +pkmEnd;
   $( "#dialogDisplayECC" ).load(url);
   dialogDisplayECC.dialog("open");

}
```

Comment: neiha, 
I tried you solution but unfortunately it did not work either.